# 'make for' in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

An [essay](http://www.ieltspodcast.com/band-9-ielts-essay-people-think-secondary-school-children-study-international-news-one-school-subjects-people-think-waste-valuable-school-time/) about the potential negative effects of introducing news channels to school curricula reads in its bottom line:

> Secondly, if international news were to become a new subject it could have a detrimental emotional impact on young minds .. The logic of having these types of stories beamed into a school to those of an impressionable age has to be challenged. Thus the obligation of watching news of a negative nature **makes for** a convincing argument against such an innovation.

What's the meaning of *make for* here? The only meaning that, in my opinion, could suit the context were :

*Tend to result in or be received as (a particular thing)* Oxford Dictionaries [online]

But, then again it doesn't make sense. What does *make for* mean here?

Comment: @J.R.: good Google-fu :) The added extra context makes an explanation a lot easier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence would mean the pretty much the same thing if you used the word *is* instead of the expression *makes for*:

> *Thus the obligation of watching news of a negative nature **is** a convincing argument against such an innovation*.

The phrase *makes for* adds a subtle hint of consequentiality. In other words, the previous points make a strong case against the premise, and build upon each other.

In this case, it's one thing to watch *negative* news, it's another to be *forced* to watch news, and yet another for *children* to watch news. But the idea of ***forcing* a *child* to watch *negative*** **news** makes for a strong case against bringing televised news to school classrooms (at least in this writer's mind).

Answer (score 2):

The definition you found makes perfect sense, actually.

> Thus the obligation of watching news of a negative nature *tends to be received as* a convincing argument against such an innovation.

In other words:

> So, [the obligation of watching news of a negative nature] *seems to be* [a convincing argument against such an innovation].

Comment: Thank you for you  reply. It's helpful, but, honestly, i'm still confused. this time then the problem seems to be with _obligation_. Would you mind telling what it means here? again the only sense i can take it to is _commitment_ or something similar. Thank you for your time.

Comment: _Obligation_ simply means _something you have to do_. So “The fact that we **have to** watch news of a negative nature”. This fact is an argument against such an innovation.